# Why this.setState() is not working in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was working with react.js and I added `this.setState()` in the constructor but it doesnt work.
Here is my code -

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      age: '18'
    }
    this.setState({id: 'name'}); 
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.id}</p>
        <p>{this.state.value}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This renders the second `p` tag but not the first why so?

Comment: why  you use setstate in constratcute ?

Comment: I was just experimenting. Curious how the setState works

Comment: you dont use `setState` in the constructor, you set `.state` directly like the line directly above your attempt. It is the only time you set it directly

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `setState()` inside constructor or inside render method

**constructor**- is called once when the instance is created if you create inside constructor rerendering won't happen.

**render** - if you use `setState()` inside the render method it will go to infinite because re-rendering happens when you use `setState()`

if you want to save such property to state do it inside lifecycle method `componentDidMount()`

Improved

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      age: '18'
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({id: 'name'}); 
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.id}</p>
        <p>{this.state.value}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

or directly put as you did for age

```
 this.state = {
      age: '18',
      id: 'name'
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The setState function, besides setting the state it also has the mechanism of re-rendering on change.

The constructor is executed before the component is actually mounted and will not render something. That's why it makes no sense to use setState in the constructor.

so you will need to achieve this like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      age: '18',
      id: 'name'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      age: '18',
      id: '',
    }
  }
​
componentDidMount(){
 this.setState({id: 'name'}); 
}
​
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.id}</p>
        <p>{this.state.age}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```